# Last item of array is returned when a function is called from another php file

Tags: php, arrays, google-analytics-api

I am a novice in PHP. I want return an array from a function in one php file and access the elements of array in another php file.

Issue I am facing is when I run the source file and print elements of array then I was able to see all tags in console but when I return the array and print it in another php file then only one item is returned or no items are returned.

source file.php

```
<?php

// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once 'C:/xxxx/google-api-php-client-2.2.4/vendor/autoload.php';


function getTags(){

    $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = 'C:/xxx/service-account-credentials.json';

    $params=array(
        'dimensions' => 'ga:dimension5,ga:dimension2',
        'filters' => 'ga:dimension5==123456'
    );
    $results =  $analytics->data_ga->get(
        'ga:' . 123456,
        '2019-08-29',
        'yesterday',
        'ga:sessions',
        $params
        );

        $rows = $results->getRows();
        $StoreTags = array();

        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($rows);$i++){

            $ExtractTag_arr = explode(',',$rows[$i][1]);

            for($j=0;$j<count($ExtractTag_arr);$j++){
                $StoreTags[]=$ExtractTag_arr[$j];
            }

            $ExtractTag_arr='';
        }

        $unique_tags = array_unique($StoreTags);
        $Unique_tags_Values = array_values(array_filter($unique_tags));
        $Count_UniqueTags = count($Unique_tags_Values);
        $Count_StoreTags=count($StoreTags);

        for($a=0;$a<$Count_UniqueTags;$a++){

            $Count_Occurances = 0;
            $UniqueTags_Value = $Unique_tags_Values[$a];

            for ($k=0;$k<$Count_StoreTags;$k++){

                if ($UniqueTags_Value == $StoreTags[$k]){

                    $Count_Occurances = $Count_Occurances+1;
                }
                else{
                    $Count_Occurances = $Count_Occurances+0;

                }
            }

           $Display_Tags=array($Unique_tags_Values[$a], $Count_Occurances);

            return  $Display_Tags;
        }

}
```

Target file:

```
<?php
include 'Source.php';

get_tags = getTags();
Print_r(getTags());
```

When I run the target.php returns nothing and if I run source.php without return statement and can print all items in `$Display_Tags`

Comment: It looks like you have your return statement inside your first `for` loop?

Comment: 1.`get_tags = getTags();` is incorrect, needs to be `$get_tags = getTags();`.2.`Print_r(getTags());` needs to be `print_r(getTags());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.`get_tags = getTags();` is incorrect, needs to be `$get_tags = getTags();`.

2.`Print_r(getTags());` needs to be `print_r(getTags());`

3.To overcome your issue put `return  $Display_Tags;` outside of the `for()` loop in your function `getTags()`.

```
<?php
include 'Source.php';

$get_tags = getTags();
print_r($get_tags);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will test and accept it as answered

Comment: Sorry for wrong update still I am getting only 1 item when called from another php file

Comment: any ideas on how to resolve, followed all your steps

Comment: @Siva if answer not worked for you then why you marked it? it states that your problem solved.

Comment: yes, sorry for that I was looking at some other point in the code, and looks like your answer worked hence marked it as answered